# Storing relational data in hadoop for analysis purpose

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hbase, relational-database

I have been reading a lot about hadoop cluster and different options to store our relational data into hadoop so we can have a centralized data cluster for both our relational and non-relational data for analysis purposes. 
But as I read more it gets more complicated. 
I don't know what would be the best way to transform my relational data into hadoop.

- Storing them in a large table in HBase (I think it would be very ugly to join all the tables)
- Storing them in different tables in Hive?
- Any other options?

I was thinking I can store each table in Hive and then use SPARK SQL to execute query. I don't know if it's the best option or not?
Can anyone help me a little with this?

Comment: Hive has its own query language; you can just use that and everything should be quite straightforward.

Comment: @BenWatson Yes, but it's very slow because of all disk processing. That's why I want to use Spark to make it faster.

Comment: Data has to be loaded into memory at some point, no matter what solution you're using. Wanting to minimise this depends entirely on the kinds of queries you're running over your data, and is probably too big for the scope of SO.

Comment: Yes, but Hive stores the intermediate result in disk which makes it fault tolerant and also slow.

Comment: Which is why I said it is impossible to answer your question without knowing the specific use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to use hadoop for OLAP purpose then its right choice you came across. Now a days Data lake is more popular than Data warehousing among the enterprise to have data at centralized place for data analytics purpose.

To answer more specific about your question to transform relational data you can use below tools,

1. **Hive**: Most popular tools to for Hadoop data warehousing, and its similar to SQL type of language for analysis. Though queries having some latency  while analyzing data, this is because data processing in on disk.
2. **HBase**: It's random and real time access to data in Hadoop and its worked on principle of Key value pair data. And doing join operation are not possible with this.

   3. **SparkSQL**: Now a days SparkSQL is more popular for data processing as everything data processed in memory of hadoop cluster and that why its faster compared to hive and query latency in seconds.

There are other tools also to analyse semi-structured, unstructured and stream data Hadoop. And this use case coming fast in coming future. So for more sustainable solution point of view Hadoop is better solution.

Comment: As I understood SparkSQL is a query Engine, But You mentioned it as a solution to store data. Am I missing something?

Comment: Spark is data processing engine only in Hadoop, every data going reside on HDFS.

Comment: I also have another question, all my relational data are in CSV files, I can store them in hdfs and create external or internal tables in hive. Does any of internal or external table have any advantages? other than by deleting external table we don't loose the data.

Comment: Please find below list of things,

1. ARCHIVE/UNARCHIVE/TRUNCATE/MERGE/CONCATENATE only work for managed tables

2. DROP deletes data for managed tables while it only deletes metadata for external ones

3. ACID/Transactional only works for managed tables

4. Query Results Caching only works for managed tables

5. Only the RELY constraint is allowed on external tables

6. Some Materialized View features only work on managed tables

Comment: Does my answer is helpful?